# How can I map IAM group to EKS cluster in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a EKS cluster and I'd like to add more IAM users to the role. I read this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html and it mentioned how to map IAM users or roles to k8s but it doesn't say how to map IAM group. Is it not supported? or is there a way to do that? I don't want to map many users one by one. When a new user join the team, I just move them to the IAM group without changing anything in EKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You can only map roles and users.  Directly from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) you linked:

> 3. Add your IAM users, roles, or AWS accounts to the configMap. You cannot add IAM groups to the configMap.

The easiest workaround would be to have a different IAM role for each group and only grant that group the ability to assume that role.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and standardized implementation for this.

I've written a blog post that addresses your exact question - [Enabling AWS IAM Group Access to an EKS Cluster Using RBAC](https://eng.grip.security/enabling-aws-iam-group-access-to-an-eks-cluster-using-rbac)

The blog covers the issue and the possible solutions. The solution we chose was to use an IAM role for each group and using a nice trick to assume it only for `kubectl` calls.

Comment: is this still the case? still cant give access to iam groups?